# How to reset an OutputStream in Java?

Tags: java, stream

I use a `GZIPOutputStream` with `ByteArrayOutputStream` to write compressed data to a string. Later on, when I am done with that string, I need to reset this stream to use it with some other string. One way is to close this stream, and create a new one. But I guess, it would be more efficient if I keep using the same stream. But to do that, I need to reset it first. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe this is an usefull link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640080/force-flush-on-a-gzipoutputstream-in-java

Comment: Why do you think it will be "more efficient"? Just throw them away and create a new one. Java is very efficient at creating new objects. There's also the issue of the internal state - who knows what attempting to "reuse" such objects will do.

Comment: I am a bit wary of JVM's garbage collection. I have the opinion that creating more objects will trigger the garbage collector more often, which I want to avoid obviously. Especially, when I have to reset this stream quite often in my program.

Comment: Donald Knuth: _"Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."_

Comment: For how long java's garbage collectors have been around you should not worry about them. Write your program as if they are perfect and make changes if there is a problem. the GC can handle millions of object creation/dereferencing in short order before stalling.

Comment: My app handles large amount of data, 10s of GBs that is. In that case, garbage collection overhead is indeed a concern.